# Array in php codeigniter framework

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am having problem with the array order problem, array coming from the database is correct but when i do print_r($data) each and every time i refresh the pages the order of the array change.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [prodtmappid] => 53624
            [totalrating] => 5.00
            [SKUNO] => C46P53624R7621
            [ProId] => 31369
            [CatId] => 46
            [proQnty] => 15
            [productMRP] => 1299
            [ProDisPrice] => 0
            [SellingPrice] => 390
            [AdditionDiscount] => 0
            [FinalPrice] => 390
            [ProDiscount] => 70
            [ProDisType] => percentage
            [ProName] => Trendy Bandey Men TB20 Yellow Tshirt
            [TotalValues] => 0.00
            [image] => MCTSTB-TB20-YL_1_55x_885.JPG
            [BrandId] => 4233
            [FDisId] => 7
            [ColorID] => 191
            [size_Val] => M
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [prodtmappid] => 9526
            [totalrating] => 0.00
            [SKUNO] => C46P9526R1870
            [ProId] => 3351
            [CatId] => 46
            [proQnty] => 8
            [productMRP] => 1899
            [ProDisPrice] => 0
            [SellingPrice] => 1329
            [AdditionDiscount] => 0
            [FinalPrice] => 1329
            [ProDiscount] => 30
            [ProDisType] => percentage
            [ProName] => FCUK 56DPJ Pink Men T-Shirt
            [TotalValues] => 0.00
            [image] => FCUK2_1_28x_885.JPG
            [BrandId] => 1285
            [FDisId] => 4
            [ColorID] => 194
            [size_Val] => S
        )
```

so what problem i am facing is array[0]['prodtmappid'] will have diffrent values on every page refress.

Comment: what is your query, are you using 'rand()' in query?

Comment: array values should be same on every refress

Comment: May there is simultaneously access to DB as well thats why id is changing over the time.

Comment: please check the link  https://www.royzez.com/index.php/webapp/deepesh/ and refresh the page every time you will refress the pages the values will change. but when I run the query in database order is same in db

Comment: can you print your query on this link? $this->db->last_query();

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY prodtmappid` to your query

Comment: @Farhan did you checked the link I am using mysql procedure so I can't use $this->db->last_query();

Comment: @riggsFolly when I am running the query it is giving me the correct result (does not change on executing the query). but when I get the data and do print_r the values suffle ..

Comment: @Deepesh I have checked the link and issue is there but i want to check the query. is there any way that you can print your query?

Comment: @farhan please check the link  and  $data = $this->supper_admin->call_procedure('proc_deepeshd',$parameter);

     print_r($data)

Comment: SHOW US THE CODE For your stored proceedure, add it to your quesiton

Comment: @riggsFolly the procedure is very big and there is no problem in stored procedure when i run the process in work bench. every time i exicute the query it is showing me the same result but when i get and print the array in php, php suffles the array.. working fine in beta server facing problem in live server only

Comment: **Ahhh, different server means different configuration**. Compare Live and Test MySQL configs and maybe PHP configs also. Also make sure the table(s) are actually setup the same

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your query? From the results, it looks like it's `ORDER BY prodQnty DESC` and `GROUP BY catId`. If you want to keep the results consistent, add `ORDER BY prodtmappid` to your query.